# Angular 1.4.1 breaks ngBindHtml

Tags: angularjs

When migrating to Angular 1.4.1 the following code didn't work anymore :

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="row in displayedElts">
     <td ng-repeat="col in tableSpec.columns" ng-bind-html="row.{{col.field}} | {{col.filter}}"></td>
</tr>
```

The error is the following :

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' is not a valid identifier at column 5 of the expression [row.{{col.field}} | {{col.filter}}] starting at [{{col.field}} | {{col.filter}}].
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update :
What i'm trying to do is the following :

- display a generic table in which row are extracted from displayedElts
  variable, columns description comes from tableSpec.columns in scope.
- Each row has columns that is accessible by name contained in
  tableSpec.columns,
- It apply a filter on each column by finding the name of the filter in
  the tableSpec.columns['name'].filter attribute.

Update 2 :
Filters which names are given by col.filter are declared regularly in Angular with such syntax :

```
angular.module('cld-apps.filters', []).
filter('cldFloatPercent', ['$translate', '$log',
    function ($translate, $log) {
            return function (floatCentValue, forceDeci) {
                if (debug) $log.debug('Into cld-apps.filters.cldPercent');
                return formatFloatCent($translate, floatCentValue, forceDeci) + ' %';
            };
}]);
```

Sorry for not giving this informations sooner. I believe it was just a matter of syntax.

Jean-Marc

Comment: Shouldn't it be `row[col.field] | col.filter`?

Comment: `ngBindHtml` expects an **expression**, that's to say (by and large) valid JavaScript. Double curly brackets aren't valid JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for reply, this expression was working well with previous release of Angular. Trying with @JBNizet suggestion leads to : Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '.' is an unexpected token at column 21 of the expression [row[col.field] | col.filter] starting at [.filter]. Removing the filter makes this works (but I need some filter)

Comment: Oh sorry. I *guess* you want `row[col.field] | filter:col.filter`. But you never said what you want to achieve, what are row, col, field and filter, and what you want the expression to do, so...

Comment: @JBNizet I try your proposal and I hav this now : Error: [filter:notarray] Expected array but received: 1200. 1200 is the value returned by row[col.field] I want to transmit to the filter named 'col.filter'

Comment: I could tell you to try all the available filters that exist. But instead why don't you tell use what you want to achieve? What are row, col, field and filter, and what do you want the expression to do?

Comment: @JBNizet you're right. I've put some explainations in text.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "generic filter". You can use `someExpr | uppercase`, or `someExpr | json`, but not `someExpr | variableThatContainsTheNameOfAFilter`. So, if you want that, you'll have to write a filter (let's name it 'apply') that consists in taking the name of another filter as argument and applying it. The expression will then be `someExpr | apply:variableThatContainsTheNameOfAFilter`.

Comment: Hum... This was working well before Angular 1.4.1. Another precision, I could make is that filters (which names comes in col.filter) are declared into my code as follow : filter('cldFloatPercent', ['$translate', '$log',
    function ($translate, $log) {
            return function (floatCentValue, forceDeci) {
                if (debug) $log.debug('Into cld-apps.filters.cldPercent');
                return formatFloatCent($translate, floatCentValue, forceDeci) + ' %';
            };
}]);

Comment: @JBNizet I've modify the text to give an example of filter declaration I use. May be it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can see on [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) link that `ng-bing-html` doesn't work this way.

you have to use expression in `ng-bind-html` like this:

Html code :

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <p ng-bind-html="myHTML"></p>
</div>
```

Script Code:

```
$scope.muHTML = "<h1>Hello World</h1>"
```

Comment: thank's for reply. This piece of code was working well before I upgrade to angular 1.4.1. I was in Angular 1.2 previously.

Comment: <tr ng-repeat-start="row in displayedElts">
     <td ng-repeat="col in tableSpec.columns" ng-bind-html="row[col.field] | col.filter"></td>
</tr>

Comment: Thank's for your reply but this doesn't work as explained in the first @JBNizet answer